# Python-My string variable won't add up into one string

Tags: python, string, variables, addition

I seem to be having issues adding a String together.
I wrote a function which I keep calling up to decode or encode a string.
The issue is when I print the result it only works to print one char out, not the whole code.
Outside of the function this method work though by adding letter after letter.
Here I use numbers.

```
def code(s,i):
  result = ""
  if i < len(s):
    if s[i] == '0':
      result += "3"
      print (result)
      code(s,i+1)
    if s[i] == '1':
      result += "4"
      print (result)
      code(s,i+1)
    else:
      print ("An Error seems to have occured.")
  else:
    print("Code is done.")
  return
```

For example if I put in: 01
I expect the result: 3
                     34
But it only prints: 3
                    4
So basically results after replaying deletes/overrides what was in the string before. 
I want to print result in one string, not multiple line after line.
This is only part of my code cut short. Why won't result add up?
This is how I defined entered.
`entered = input("Please type something.")`

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?  What behavior do you expect that you aren't seeing?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, What are you trying to achieve, i.e. what are the values for s and i? What output do you get? What ouput did you expect? Please [edit] your question and add some details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue.
Everytime I recalled the function it resetted my code, so I passed result as a 
parameter of my function:

```
def code(s,i,result):

  if i < len(s):
    if s[i] == '0':
      result += "3"
      print (result)
      code(s,i+1,result)
      return
    if s[i] == '1':
      result += "4"
      print (result)
      code(s,i+1,result)
      return
    else:
      print ("An Error seems to have occured.")
  else:
    print("Code is done.")
  return
```

Now result prints out what I needed, thanks for any help! ^^

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is right but only one problem that after passing the first nested if clause the code further goes to the next one, it goes into the nested else clause.

To stop this you have to return the program

You should make your code like this.

```
def code(s,i):
  result = ""
  if i < len(s):
    if s[i] == '0':
      result += "3"
      print (result)
      code(s,i+1)
      return
    if s[i] == '1':
      result += "4"
      print (result)
      code(s,i+1)
      return
    else:
      print ("An Error seems to have occured.")
  else:
    print("Code is done.")
  return
```

Comment: Thank you, this has taken the message of an error away.